# como puedo obtener el valor especifico de un array de objetos?

Tags: angular, typescript

como se ve en el codigo tengo un array de objetos donde primero tengo un "dataResponse" y despues un "product", cuando intento obtener un valor dentro de "product" como por ejemplo amount, el consol.log me regresa "undefine" mi pregunta es como puedo obtener el valor de amount?

```
this.service.product().subscribe( resp => console.log(resp.dataResponse.product.amount))

    {
        "httpStatus": {
            "statusCode": ,
            "statusDesc": ""
        },
        "dataResponse": {
            "product": [
                {
                    "reference": "",
                    "Type": "",
                    "date": "",
                    "amount": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

[image: console log]

Comment: Te recomiendo aprender qué es un array y cómo se recorre. Intentar hacer una aplicación con angular sin conocer Javascript es como correr sin saber caminar

Answer (score 0):

Reproducí tu error, pasa por que product es un arreglo de objetos, prueba de la siguiente manera:

```js
const testJson = {
    "httpStatus": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "statusDesc": ""
    },
    "dataResponse": {
        "product": [
            {
                "reference": "",
                "Type": "",
                "date": "",
                "amount": "10000"
            }
        ]
    }
};

console.log(testJson.dataResponse.product[0].amount);
```

Saludos;